# Unable to publish Windows Phone 8.1 application from Visual Studio 2013 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

When I click on Store Menu -> Associate App with the Store ... OR Create App Packages I got the following error: 
An unexpected network error has occurred. The app list cannot be refreshed. Please retry by pressing the Refresh button.
[image]

Even I can't upload the appx files because it fails when checking the app identity and publisher ...
I appreciate your help
Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, it seems to be working now, MS fixed the issue.

Comment: I am having the same problem at the moment (07/17/2015), trying to submit my app from VS2013 or VS2015 so it seems this problem exists again. :(

Comment: Still a problem as of 2015/07/23.  Contacted support.  Seems to be due to a bogus app in the dev center.  They did not give me an eta on a fix.

Comment: still a problem 2015/08/03

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a store problem. I'm talking to Microsoft's support, trying to get a feedback for the service to be back up.

Update:
Microsoft seems to have fixed the issue, which really was on their side.

Please, try again, as it should be all ok now. I've tested and it is all working.

Answer (score 1):

We are facing the same issue. This thread [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/cf578dab-79f2-46ab-a2aa-50a46041ea20/error-an-unexpected-network-error-has-occured-the-app-list-cannot-be-refreshed-please-retry-by?forum=windowsstore) says something about large number of apps that could be the reason. We have only 3 apps on the list. So it doesn't really seem to be the reason. Its the same with  both Windows Phone and the Store apps. Accessing dashboard in the browser seems to be unaffected. 
Also, I tried different ISPs to rule out that reason.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue for the last 2 days. It works fine now. It was probably due to the account migration(so not all user would have faced this issue) and unrelated to the count of apps.
Can you try again?